# Android native app resolves hostname to a different IP from browser

Tags: android, dns, ip-address

I'm having a *really* strange problem.  I am supporting a private mobile app for a client that connects to their website to perform a variety of operation.  For reasons beyond my control, the IP address of the website has changed, while the hostname, obviously, stayed the same.  The DNS zone has been updated accordingly. Now the client states that mobile apps are unable to connect to the website.

I am trying to debug the issue and I'm seeing this very strange behaviour: while a mobile browser (Chrome and Brave) on an android phone successfully connect to the website on the new IP address, the mobile app still attempts to connect to the old IP address.  I added `Log.d` to resolve and log the IP address for the hostname (the app is only trying to connect to a hostname, e.g. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) - and I can see that it's still the old IP address.  I'm very confused - as the browser running on the same device on the same network connects successfully.

What am I missing?  And how can I force the app to correctly resolve the address?

Answer (score 0):

This really was strange - but after two (2) device restarts everything started working as expected.